# What are the word-order categories "Subject", "verb", "object" called?

Tags: terminology

Categories like "Noun" and "Adjective" can be said to be lexical categories. But what are categories like "subject" and "object" called?

Comment: The phrases "core arguments" and "oblique" seems to cover a lot of scenarios. Core arguments would cover all the variations on nominative-accusative, subject-object, ergative–absolutive and so on. Oblique does a reasonably good job of referring to everything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Subject** and **object** are names of **grammatical function** categories.
 
The grammatical function of a constituent in a sentence is determined by its relation to other constituents in the sentence. The subject, for example, is what the meaning of the **predicate** is predicated of, and it also agrees with the **head** of the predicate - the main verb, if there is one - in person, number and gender. Note that **verb** is not a grammatical function category but a **syntactic category**. The verb in a sentence realizes the grammatical function of head of the predicate (sometimes called the *predicator*), as can be seen in the syntactic structure tree below, where the grammatical function categories appears in blue. You can read a little more about this distinction 
[here](http://contextors.com/Syntactic-Structure-Trees#ref=1099).

[image: An example of a syntactic structure tree]
[enlarge image](http://contextors.com/examples/he_ate_the_cake.html#ref=1099)

Comment: This is all true only of English grammar. Verb agreement, for instance, varies widely from language to language, and is frequently absent. The grammatical categories of _Subject_ and _Direct Object_ also vary from language to language; there is no such thing as a "Subject" or "Object", for instance, in a transitive sentence which uses the Ergative argument system, which is common in many languages.